# Using PHP with charts and MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, google-visualization

I'm using google charts to output a very simple pie chart

```
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Games', 'Number'],
      ['Win',     11],
      ['Lose',      2]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Win/Lose Ratio'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

However, in place of the values for Win and Lose, I want to pull 2 numbers out of my database. This doesn't need any kind of loop, just a way to reference 2 specific fields on a row instead of the values 11 and 2. This is the SQL query I'm using to get those two values

```
$qry =("SELECT games_won, games_lost FROM Members where member_id = '".$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']."'");
$result = mysql_query($qry);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$won = $row[games_won];
$lost = $row[games_lost];
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

I've had a look at a lot of other FAQ's on the subject but they all deal with a collection of values in the same field and looping through severals rows of data, as opposed to referencing specific entries in the database.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Games', 'Number'],
      ['Win',     <?php echo($won); ?>],
      ['Lose',     <?php echo($lost); ?>]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Win/Lose Ratio'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

All you are doing is grabbing the values, then `echo`ing them out into your JavaScript.  Please do note that I am not error checking, that is something you will need to think about when directly injecting values into HTML or JavaScript!

A better way of doing this is writing your code as a [RESTful API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).  Have your SQL code in a place that you can send a `member_id` as a `GET` request.  That, in turn, can print out the games won/lost inside `JSON`.  Than, you can preform an AJAX request and grab those values to populate your table (just reference the values inside the returned `JSON` as regular JavaScript variables).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, works great! I'm getting quite a lot of really good advice every time I ask a question, with someone usually telling me there is a better way of doing something, even though it may take me longer to figure out. You're suggestion will definitely be another one to add to the list that I'm currently working my way through! Thanks again :-)